# How solve 403 forbidden error in vix cluste server when trying to load livewire script?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, production-environment

I did upload my webapp on shared hosting yesterday, I am using Laravel 10 with Livewire 3, and i am getting this error in production in console

```
livewire.min.js?id=6b5eb707 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
```

In development everything works fine, but in production, it cant find livewire script and I don't have idea why..My shared hosting is using  cluster VIX server. If anyone have experience with this, I will be glad for every advice, thank you.

Comment: This is probably related to your Nginx Virtualhost configuration. Please share the config for your host.

Comment: @Repox sorry..made mistake, that's not Nginx, its cluster vix server